# Let $m_X(t)$ be the moment generating function of random variable $X$. Prove $m_X(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty E(X^k)\frac{t^k}{k!}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

> Let $m_X(t)$ be the moment generating function of random variable $X$. Prove $m_X(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty E(X^k)\frac{t^k}{k!}$

So I have:

$$
\begin{split}
m_X(t)
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{tX} \right]\\
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(tX)^k}{k!} \right] \\
 &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{E}\left[ X^k \right] \\
 &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!} \mathbb{E}\left[ X^k \right]
\end{split}
$$

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $X$ is discrete or continuous: expected value is linear.  However, there is an issue of convergence.  $m_X(t)$ exists and has that value if the sum converges absolutely.  But there are random variables for which even $E(X)$ does not exist.

Comment: @RobertIsrael So does the rest just follow from linearity of expected value? I have edited to show. Or is convergence still something I have to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the  question precise I will assume that $Ee^{tX} <\infty$ for  all $t$. Since $e^{|tX|} \leq e^{tX}+e^{-tX}$ we get $Ee^{|tX|} <\infty $ and so  $E\sum_n \frac {|t^{n} |X^{n}} {n!} <\infty$. We can now invoke Fubini/Tonelli Theorem to justify the interchage of the sum and the expecation.